# C# -> Windows Form New Window Show Trouble

Tags: c#, winforms, new-window

I'm trying to create a new window using Windows Forms, and I'm getting this error:

> " 'whichDiceGameForm' does not contain a definition for 'show' and no extension method 'show' accepting a first argument of type 'whichDiceGameForm' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) "

```
       public partial class mainForm : Form
{
    public mainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        title.Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold);

    }

    private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radioDice.Tag = new whichDiceGameForm();
        radioCard.Tag = new whichCardGame();

        mainForm f = null;
        if (radioDice.Checked)
            f = new whichDiceGameForm();
        else
          if (radioCard.Checked)
            f = new whichCardGame();

        f.Show();
    }

    }
```

EDIT* here is the whichDiceGameForm code:

```
    public partial class whichDiceGameForm : Form
{
    public whichDiceGameForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void whichDiceGameForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: How about showing us the code of "whichDiceGameForm"? Because apparently you never gave it a show function. Did you properly inherit it form Form like mainForm?

Comment: `show()` and `Show()` are different in case you went snow blind ;)

Comment: @Christopher I just added it.

Comment: @FortyTwo omg I'm so blind hahaahha

Comment: intellisense helps to avoid such mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote "show" in lower case. First letter should be in upper case: "Show"

What's more you break language conventions (class names in lower case, local variables starting with upper case...)

Comment: do you know how I can enable the button in the common radio click event?

Comment: Yes. startButton.Enabled = true. You do so. But you split this into two methods. All two radios should have common Click or Changed event. Do you know what "sender" is?

Comment: No I'm a little confused, I'll update the code I posted to show what I have. The problem is I am required to have both radio boxes set intially to unchecked.

Comment: Sender parameter gives you the object that made event to happen. So for example in your method: radioDice_CheckedChanged sender parameter is radioDice. Now if you have one method and two radios, then "sender" parameter would give you the radio that made event to fire.